# Live Charts - Adding data to the second Y axis

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have got my Live Charts Cartesian->Line Chart plotting 5 different types of data from a file/serial port but they are all on the same series.

I have 2 Y axis showing but cannot add data to each on the fly. The live charts documentation is terrible.

I have created 2 series but the data does not seem to plot.

<lvc:CartesianChart  x:Name="lc_MainChart" Hoverable="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DisableAnimations="True" LegendLocation="Right" Loaded="CartesianChart_Loaded" Margin="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" >

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX >
     <lvc:Axis Title="DATA POINTS" FontSize="18" MinValue="0" MaxValue="512" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
     <lvc:Axis Title="MOTOR VOLTAGE (mV)" FontSize="18" MinValue="0" MaxValue="8000" ></lvc:Axis>
     <lvc:Axis Title="MOTOR CURRENT (mA)" FontSize="18" MinValue="0" MaxValue="800" Position="RightTop" ></lvc:Axis>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>

     <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
          <lvc:LineSeries Name="Chart1" Values="{Binding ChartValues}"/>
          <lvc:LineSeries Name="Chart2" Values="{Binding ChartValues2}"/>
     </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
</lvc:CartesianChart>

// Setup chart
ChartSeries = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
           Title = "Motor Current",
           Values = new ChartValues<Int16> {0},
           PointForeground = Brushes.Red,
           PointGeometry = null
    },
    new LineSeries
    {
           Title = "Voltage",
           Values = new ChartValues<Int16> {0},
           PointForeground = Brushes.Blue,
           PointGeometry = null
    }
};

// Setup chart series
ChartSeries2 = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
           Title = "Motor Speed",
           Values = new ChartValues<Int16> {0},
           PointForeground = Brushes.Green,
           PointGeometry = null
    },
    new LineSeries
    {
           Title = "Force",
           Values = new ChartValues<Int16> {0},
           PointForeground = Brushes.Blue,
           PointGeometry = null
    }
};

YFormatter = value => value.ToString("F");

lc_MainChart.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;

ChartSeries[0].Values.Add(MotorCurrent[i]);
ChartSeries[1].Values.Add(VBat[i]);

ChartSeries2[0].Values.Add(MotorSpeed[i]);
ChartSeries2[1].Values.Add(Force[i]);

DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
      <lvc:LineSeries Name="Chart1" Values="{Binding ChartValues}" ScalesYAt="1"/>
      <lvc:LineSeries Name="Chart2" Values="{Binding ChartValues2}" ScalesYAt="0"/>
 </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
```

just add ScalesYAt="[index of axis]" property to LineSerie,
hope save your time.